# REST Api calls to google big query

Tags: rest, google-bigquery

I am trying to make a rest api call for google big query from the terminal.
I tried with bq query which works.

```
bq query 'select count(*) from publicdata:samples.shakespeare'
```

Just wondering what is the rest end point for bq? Or is there any http rest api call for big query which can be executed from the terminal?

Something like

```
Get http://...//'select count(*) from publicdata:samples.shakespeare'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google BigQuery provides few APIs to execute query in async and sync manner

**[Insert Job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert)**:
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/projectId/jobs
and
POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectId/jobs

This API starts a new asynchronous job. Requires the Can View project role.

**[Query Job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query)**
POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectId/queries

This API runs a BigQuery SQL query and returns results if the query completes within a specified timeout.

You can see more details at [BigQuery API Reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/)

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. I am trying to execute a sql query, in query job, can i specify the query explicitly or should i execute it in console and provide the job id here:

I am trying for something like this:

POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/red-road-574/queries/'SELECT * FROM [projectid:Test.FinalCluster] ORDER BY HId, TId, StartTime, StopTime limit 10'

Its a simple api call, so i dont mind if it gets executed synchronously.

Please correct me if i have misunderstood it.

Comment: If it were GET method - you would be able to pass query text as a query string. But there is no GET method for this. Rather POST method where you need to pass query text as well as other resources in Request Body. See multiple examples in links within the answer

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant the link you specified here https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectId/queries is giving me a 404. Is that endpoint dead now?

Comment: Is this perhaps the correct url?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query

Answer (score 1):

All requests should be relative to `https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2`, per the [REST reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/). For the `query` API, for example, you would send a POST request to `https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/your_project_id/queries` using the request body outlined as part of the [jobs.query reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query).

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> BigQuery API Reference
>
> This API reference is organized by resource type. Each resource type
>   has one or more data representations and one or more methods.
>
> You can see the API definition file listing all methods and resources
>   at https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/bigquery/v2/rest

I think this is what you're looking for: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/